# Convert string with multiple dict to one dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert string to dict but string contains multiple dictionaries, so how can I convert it please help

```
'{"pr2":[2,"Hair Dryer(Fashion)","₹1499.00","home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png","2"],"pr5":[1,"Bowls(Season bowls )","₹499","home/images/balls_season.png","5"]}{"pr2":[2,"Hair Dryer(Fashion)","₹1499.00","home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png","2"],"pr5":[1,"Bowls(Season bowls )","₹499","home/images/balls_season.png","5"]}'
```

Please convert it to one dictionary

Comment: Try `json.loads`

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's a **dictionary** - not a "dictionery"

Comment: I already tried json.loads but it showing error like "Extra data: line 1 column 156 (char 155)"

Answer (score 0):

*Quick-and-dirty* way would be using `str.replace` to repair the string to correct Json format. But I'd recommend to fix the root cause and change how this string is produced.

```py
import json

s = '{"pr2":[2,"Hair Dryer(Fashion)","₹1499.00","home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png","2"],"pr5":[1,"Bowls(Season bowls )","₹499","home/images/balls_season.png","5"]}{"pr2":[2,"Hair Dryer(Fashion)","₹1499.00","home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png","2"],"pr5":[1,"Bowls(Season bowls )","₹499","home/images/balls_season.png","5"]}'

data = json.loads("[" + s.replace("}{", "},{") + "]")
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "pr2": [
            2,
            "Hair Dryer(Fashion)",
            "₹1499.00",
            "home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png",
            "2",
        ],
        "pr5": [1, "Bowls(Season bowls )", "₹499", "home/images/balls_season.png", "5"],
    },
    {
        "pr2": [
            2,
            "Hair Dryer(Fashion)",
            "₹1499.00",
            "home/images/hairdetyerxyz.png",
            "2",
        ],
        "pr5": [1, "Bowls(Season bowls )", "₹499", "home/images/balls_season.png", "5"],
    },
]
```